# Hard line breaks in Revolution R IDE

Tags: visual-studio, r

Is there a way to introduce hard breaks (say at 80 characters) with a tabbed next line, in the [Revolution R IDE](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/products/revolution-r.php), a functionality that Rstudio has?

PS. I have added the Visual Studio tag since Revolution R is built on top of VS.

---

I had another question which is now resolved:

Is there a keyboard shortcut to send a selection to the console;

**Edit**: Okay, so I figured out how to do this. The function is `Edit.RunLineorSelection`, and is mapped to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> keys.

Comment: @paulhiemstra you edited part of the answer out in your edit!

Comment: Asking several questions in one post is not encouraged. If you have two questions, just create two posts. In addition, if you have an answer to your own question, just post it as an answer and accept it. In addition, the shortcut question is very trivial as this is very easy to find in either the documentation, or the list of shortcuts in the IDE.